# JavaScript Timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select all the elements of a class. Then change that class to another class . After 0.5 seconds i want to revert the elements back to their original class. I must do this 8 times in a row. Even though my code achieves that(in a way) i can't see the color changes in the buttons . Can anyone help me ? it's a timing problem i guess. Here is the js code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#start').click(function(){
        game();
    })

    function game(){
        var ordine = new Array();
        for(var t = 1; t <= 8; t++){
            var y = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < t; k++) {
                var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
                ordine[y++] = x;
                change1(x);
                setTimeout(change2(x), 500);
            }
        }
    }

    function change1(y){
        var z = 'cls' + y;
        var t = 'cls' + y + 2;
        $("." + z).removeClass(z).addClass(t);
    }

    function change2(y){
        var z = 'cls' + y + 2;
        var t = 'cls' + y;
        $("." + z).removeClass(z).addClass(t);
    }
})
```

Here you can find the full code(html,css and js)
http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5VK/2/

Comment: You've run into some trouble with closures. Here's some more recommended reading -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the following line:

```
setTimeout(change2(x), 500);
```

You are calling the function `change2` here, passing its return value to setTimeout.
What you actually want though is to call the change2 function after 500ms. Change your code to:

```
setTimeout(function() { change2(x); }, 500);
```

That way, you are passing an anonymous function to setTimout, which will then be executed by it after 500ms.

EDIT: I've modified your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cx5VK/7/ stripping out a lot of code that didn't do anything in that sample (you quite possibly need it elsewhere):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start').click(function () {
        game();
    })

    function game() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        change1(x);
    }

    function change1(y) {
        var z = 'cls' + y;
        var t = 'cls' + y + 2;
        $("." + z).removeClass(z).addClass(t);
        setTimeout(function() { change2(y); }, 500);
    }

    function change2(y) {
        var z = 'cls' + y + 2;
        var t = 'cls' + y;
        $("." + z).removeClass(z).addClass(t);
        game();
    }
});
```

Now, the `game` function simply gets a random number and calls `change1` with that number as parameter. `change1` itself will set the timeout to reset the color for that square via `change2`. At the end of that function, the game is "restarted" by a simple call to `game()`, to get another random number and so on and so forth. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: you are indeed right , but it seems i have a problem with the way i thought about the problem. I need 1 of the buttons to turn to another color then after 0.5 seconds i want that button reverted back to it's original color . After that i need the next button to change color and so on . The code i have just changes back the last button it seems ... help ?

Comment: i need to stop for iterating before change2 is finished. And i can't find a wait function

Comment: I've modified the answer, adding code - hope it helps. :)

Comment: that is for an infinite number of iteratios, isn't it ? i just want 8. I need a sequence of 8 random numbers from 1-4 (because i have 4 buttons and each button has a number) . This sequence i want it in an array in order(so if the first random number was 1 then the first number in that array is 1), after that i want the button with the number 1 to change color(which i do by changing the class) after exactly 0.5 miliseconds i want button 1 to change back and i want another random number. The process must repeat 8 times.. this is what i am trying to do :(.

Comment: I need to stop it after a certain number of iterations. Because the game is gradual , first level just 1 button changes, 2nd level 2 buttons change and in the 8th level i have a sequence of 8 button changes . I am sorry i am writing so much :)) ! only if you have the time bother to answer me i am trying to figure it out myself. Your answer is perfect :D